# "Source not found." when getting a char from user

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

"Source not found." appears when the program try to get a char from user.
What character I input for testing is '3'. We can also encounter the same problem when we try other characters except '5'.

Code:

```
package assignment1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main_menu {

    private static char main_menu_choice = '0';

    private static void setMainMenuChoice(char choice) {
        main_menu_choice = choice;
    }
    private static char getMainMenuChoice() {
        return main_menu_choice;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            showMainMenu();
            setMainMenuChoice( getChoiceFromUser() );
        } while (getMainMenuChoice() != '5');
    }

    private static void showMainMenu() {
        System.out.println("----------------Main Menu----------------");
        System.out.println("1. Initialize the address book");
        System.out.println("2. Create person contact information");
        System.out.println("3. Lookup person contact information");
        System.out.println("4. Lookup all person contact information");
        System.out.println("5. Quit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
    }

    private static char getChoiceFromUser() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); <--------"Source not found."
        char choice = reader.next().charAt(0);
        reader.close();
        return choice;
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The issue here is that you are creating your `Scanner` more than once (similar to [this question][1]). Try moving your `reader` so that it is only instantiated once, and don't close it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766566/java-multiple-scanners

Comment: @EvanKnowles Have you tried it on your machine?

Comment: This is definitely not a debugging source not found issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the application for example to create the Scanner on start and closing it when the application exits.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        showMainMenu();
        setMainMenuChoice(getChoiceFromUser(reader));
    } while (getMainMenuChoice() != '5');
    reader.close();
}
```

.
.
.

```
private static char getChoiceFromUser(Scanner reader) {
    char choice = reader.next().charAt(0);
    return choice;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I get another exception, when try to run your code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

So first of all you need to delete `reader.close();` because you try to close `System.in` and this is not a good idea.

From Java Doc's:

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

Comment: Nope. System.in does not implement Closeable as far as I know, and also it is standard practice to close your Scanner upon being done using it.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner I know that System.in does not implement Closeable interface, I don't wrote it. I wrote that this guy "try to close System.in and this is not a good idea", exactly because System.in does not implement Closeable interface.

Answer (score -1):

A possible way of doing what was suggested in the comments would be:

```
package assignment1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main_menu {

    private static char main_menu_choice = '0';
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static void setMainMenuChoice(char choice) {
        main_menu_choice = choice;
    }
    private static char getMainMenuChoice() {
        return main_menu_choice;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            showMainMenu();
            setMainMenuChoice( getChoiceFromUser() );
            System.out.println(main_menu_choice);
        } while (getMainMenuChoice() != '5');
        reader.close();
    }

    private static void showMainMenu() {
        System.out.println("----------------Main Menu----------------");
        System.out.println("1. Initialize the address book");
        System.out.println("2. Create person contact information");
        System.out.println("3. Lookup person contact information");
        System.out.println("4. Lookup all person contact information");
        System.out.println("5. Quit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
    }

    private static char getChoiceFromUser() {
         //<--------"Source not found."
        char choice = reader.next().charAt(0);

        return choice;
    }
}
```

So if your main_menu class is instantiated a Scanner is created and after quitting it is closed. Also I printed out the choice the user made to see if it is working.