# Scanner gets skipped

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get 2 integers from the user. This is the related part of my code:

```
 public void play() {

        int row=0,col=0;
        initializeboard();
        printboard();

        do {

            currentPlayer = players.remove();  //Returns currentPlayer
            System.out.println("Ok, "+ currentPlayer.getname() + ", Enter your Move: Row[1-3] & Column[1-3]");
            Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (choice.hasNext()) {

                row = choice.nextInt();
                col = choice.nextInt();
                while (row<1 || row>3 || col<1 || col>3 || board[row-1][col-1] != '-' ) {
                    System.out.println("Well, Move is not Valid or has already Been Selected, Try Again :/");
                    row = choice.nextInt();
                    col = choice.nextInt();
                }
                choice.close();
            }

            board[row][col] = currentPlayer.getsign(); //Places Sign in Game Board
            printboard();
            System.out.println();
            players.append(currentPlayer); //Inserts the Next Player
        } while(!win() && !isFull());
}
```

At first, it throws a `NoSuchElementException`, so I used `.hasNext()`. Now, it just skips the scanner and immediately invokes `printboard()`.

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: There must be another part of the code that creates the problem, because just setting up a simple `Scanner`, there is no problem at all.

Comment: I don`t think it will be possible to find any solution showing us just this part of your code. Can you show us your other codes for this project, which maybe are related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: @LAD  I added more detail...

Comment: For more specifics answers about your problem, please provide a [mcve]. There is so many method and variable not provided here ...

Comment: Don't forget to check [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating and then closing multiple `Scanner` objects with the same stream.

The answer from Peter Lawrey in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766566/java-multiple-scanners?answertab=votes#tab-top) explains why you shouldn't create multiple `Scanner` objects from the same stream. Here is a quote from the answer:

> Once you close a stream it closes the underlying stream and you can't use it again. Only close System.in if you want to prevent it being used again.

The best thing is to create one `final` `Scanner` object (per stream) in your program and just pass it into methods when you want to use it:

```
static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: well, I think I figured it out...I have another scanner in my main method that gets name & sign from user ,before getting row & col; now I just removed scanner from main and put it in play...now the scanner in play works fine. seems like more than one scanner causes problems even if they are closed :/

Comment: @Lenny You don't want more than one `Scanner` of the same stream.

Comment: That will not be a permanent "fix" since you can still call `play` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem :

```
do {
    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
    [...]
    choice.close();
} while (!win() && !isFull());
```

You are opening a `Scanner` in a loop (first mistake) but more important, you are closing the `Scanner`.
Closing a `Scanner` also close the `InputStream` used, in your case `System.in`. You can't open that stream again so you will never be able to execute your loop twice.

[`public void close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29)

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked.

And this is in fact the problem you are facing. Once you have closed the first `Scanner` created and then try to open a new one, since `System.in` is closed, there is no value to read (`hasNext` return false). And you most likely enter an infinite loop since `!win() && !isFull()` will always give the same result.

I suggest not close it (in this case, this is not always a bad thing since it is a local variable, there is no risk).
Or simply use a parameter in the method to provide it (and still not closing it in the method). Let the `main` method manage the `Scanner`.

```
public void play(Scanner choice){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have been throwing the *NoSuchElementException* because you didn't input a integer.

The reason it "skips" over the `Scanner` is possibly because all `hasNext` evalutes is whether the `System.in` has a `String` contained in it. So it evalutes that expression and returns `true` or `false`. Your program then evaluates the expression in the while loop, possibly finding it to be false. Then finally moving on and invoking `printboard`.

I would suggest going back and changing `hasNext` to

```
row = choice.nextInt();
col = choice.nextInt();
```

Then make sure you are inputting integers.

Comment: He said he changed it to hasNext