# How to fix "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found" and other two errors?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm java beginner, and I wanted to make To-Do list. The problem is I made scanner function with a lot of useless code and the main problem is that, when I click '1' to finish the To-Do list everything works fine, but when I click '0' to continue doing list i get 3 errors in eclipse:

I really want to get rid of that and still practice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToDo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Put in task: ");
      String task1 = input1.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Is that all?  ");
      double answer1 = input1.nextDouble();
      input1.close();
      if(answer1 == 1) {
          System.out.println("Your tasks are:\n" + task1);
          System.exit(0);
      } else if(answer1 == 0) {
          System.out.println("\n");
      }
      Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Put in task: ");
      String task2 = input2.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Is that all?  ");
      double answer2 = input2.nextDouble();
      input2.close();
      if(answer2 != 0) {
          System.out.println("Your tasks are:\n" + task1 + task2);
          System.exit(0);
      } else if(answer2 != 1) {
          System.out.println("\n");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `No line found` error occurs because you're constructing an additional scanner. Rather than create an `input1` and `input2` scanner you can reuse the first scanner

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you do `input1.close();`, it is also closing the `System.in` input stream.

Ideally you should use the same scanner object, but you can also make your code *work* by removing `input1.close();`.

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766566/java-multiple-scanners).