# Interger array where the user enters the index and the element is printed on screen

Tags: java, arrays

I tried entering an array and print only a certain index element
Forgive me if my question is stupid, I am a beginner,
The code runs but throws an exception when it reaches to the enter n part on line no 12
this is my code down below

```
import java.util.*;
public class array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ??classof 5 students
        int []a=new int[5];
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }sc.close();
        System.out.println("enter n");
        int n = ob.nextInt();
        System.out.println(","+a[n]+",");
   

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception? what is on line 12?

Comment: "*The code runs but throws an exception when it reaches to the enter n part on line no 12*" - Please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line throwing the exception.

Comment: You don't need two instances of `Scanner` and you definitely don't need to close any of them until after you print the value, if ever.

Comment: The thing is that when you `close()` a `Scanner`, it'll close the underlying stream. So in your case, `System.in` is closed, and because both `Scanner`s are bound to `System.in`, both `Scanner`s cannot be used again.

Comment: It is generally a good idea to close a stream when you're done with it. However, `System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err` are exceptions to this rule: they are wired by the JVM at startup, so the JVM is responsible for closing them. As a rule of thumb: don't close what you didn't open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reuse the same scanner object to read multiple times.
So removing the object `ob` and using `sc` will help.
Also, do not close the `sc` scanner.
Refer to this for more details: [Java Multiple Scanners][1].

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766566/java-multiple-scanners#:~:text=Having%20multiple%20scanners%20(on%20same,consume%20the%20stream%20they%20share.&text=a%20reference%20to%20the%20source,buffer%20used%20to%20hold%20input